# Remove features of json if lat-lon keys not within other json boundaries

Tags: python, json, plotly, geojson, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a weather contour for the United States from an existing data frame and add it to a Dash Mapbox map, but the json file I am creating "fills in" areas where data does not exist in an attempt to fill out the entire array. The unwanted data can be seen shaded in the image below.

[image]

I'd like to remove data from the weather json file where the lat-longs from the weather json file and the states json file do not intersect.

Better yet would be a solution where weather data was never created at all for areas outside of the states_20m.geojson.

The pertinent data files can be found at this [GitHub Link](https://github.com/jkiefn1/SO_Json_Question). They are the weather dataframe and the states_20m.geojson.

Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata,RectSphereBivariateSpline,Rbf
import geojsoncontour
import json
import branca
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage
from geojson import Feature, Polygon, dump
import geopandas as gpd


##### Load in the main DataFrame and define vars#####
path = r'date_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=[0])

col = 'Day_Temp'
temp_levels = [-20,0,10,20,32]
levels = temp_levels
unit = 'deg F'
colors = ['#f0ffff','#add8e6','#7bc8f6','#069af6','#0343df'

##### Create the weather contour #####

data = []

df_copy = df.copy()

##### Create the GEOJSON Layer #####
vmin   = 0
vmax   = 1
cm     = branca.colormap.LinearColormap(colors, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax).to_step(len(levels))


x_orig = (df_copy.long.values.tolist())
y_orig = (df_copy.lat.values.tolist())
z_orig = np.asarray(df_copy[col].values.tolist())


x_arr          = np.linspace(np.min(x_orig), np.max(x_orig), 5000)
y_arr          = np.linspace(np.min(y_orig), np.max(y_orig), 5000)
x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(x_arr, y_arr)

xscale = df_copy.long.max() - df_copy.long.min()
yscale = df_copy.lat.max() - df_copy.lat.min()

scale = np.array([xscale, yscale])


z_mesh = griddata((x_orig, y_orig), z_orig, (x_mesh, y_mesh), method='linear')


sigma = [5, 5]
z_mesh = sp.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(z_mesh, sigma, mode='nearest')

# Create the contour
contourf = plt.contourf(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh, levels, alpha=0.9, colors=colors, 
                        linestyles='none', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

# Convert matplotlib contourf to geojson
geojson = geojsoncontour.contourf_to_geojson(
    contourf=contourf,
    min_angle_deg=3,
    ndigits=2,
    unit=unit,
    stroke_width=1,
    fill_opacity=0.3)
d = json.loads(geojson)
len_features=len(d['features'])
if not data:
    data.append(d)
else:
    for i in range(len(d['features'])):
         data[0]['features'].append(d['features'][i])

weather_json = json.loads(geojson)

###### Create the DataFrame #####

lats = [30,33,35,40]
lons = [-92,-94,-96,-100]
dat = [1000,2000,500,12500]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lats,lons,dat)), columns = ['lat', 'lon', 'data'])

##### Add the two on top of on another in a Dash Mapbox #####

# reading in the geospatial data for the state boundaries
with open('States_20m.geojson') as g:
    states_json = json.load(g)

column = "data"
fig = px.density_mapbox(
    df,
    lat="lat",
    lon="lon",
    z=column,
    hover_data={
        "lat": True,  # remove from hover data
        "lon": True,  # remove from hover data
        column: True,
    },
    center=dict(lat=38.5, lon=-96),
    zoom=3,
    radius=30,
    opacity=0.4,
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    color_continuous_scale=['rgb(0,0,0)',
                             'rgb(19,48,239)',
                             'rgb(115,249,253)',
                             'rgb(114,245,77)',
                             'rgb(254,251,84)',
                             'rgb(235,70,38)'],
    range_color = [0, 2000]
)

# Weather outlines
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": f,
                "line": {"width":1},
#                 "type":"line",
                "type":"fill",
                "color": f["properties"]["fill"],
                "opacity": 1,
            }
            for f in weather_json["features"]
        ],
    }
)

# States outlines
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": g,
                "line": {"width":1},
                "type":"line",
                "color": 'black',
                "opacity": 0.5,
            }
            for g in states_json["features"]
        ],
    }
)
    
fig.show()
```

Comment: Please define the following variables in your code:  `colors`, `levels`, `col` and `unit` to be able to reproduce your question and we can help you.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention. Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of each weather contour as a polygon and the outline of the US as another polygon. What you need is the overlap of the US polygon with each contour polygon.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata,RectSphereBivariateSpline,Rbf
import geojsoncontour
import json
import branca
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage
from geojson import Feature, Polygon, dump
import geopandas as gpd
from urllib.request import urlopen
import shapely.geometry
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, GeometryCollection, Polygon, mapping
from shapely.ops import unary_union

##### Load in the main DataFrame and define vars#####
df = pd.read_csv(r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkiefn1/SO_Json_Question/main/date_data.csv', index_col=[0])

col = 'Day_Temp'
temp_levels = [-20,0,10,20,32]
levels = temp_levels
unit = 'deg F'
colors = ['#f0ffff','#add8e6','#7bc8f6','#069af6','#0343df']

##### Create the weather contour #####

data = []

df_copy = df.copy()

##### Create the GEOJSON Layer #####
vmin   = 0
vmax   = 1
cm     = branca.colormap.LinearColormap(colors, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax).to_step(len(levels))


x_orig = (df_copy.long.values.tolist())
y_orig = (df_copy.lat.values.tolist())
z_orig = np.asarray(df_copy[col].values.tolist())


x_arr          = np.linspace(np.min(x_orig), np.max(x_orig), 5000)
y_arr          = np.linspace(np.min(y_orig), np.max(y_orig), 5000)
x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(x_arr, y_arr)

xscale = df_copy.long.max() - df_copy.long.min()
yscale = df_copy.lat.max() - df_copy.lat.min()

scale = np.array([xscale, yscale])


z_mesh = griddata((x_orig, y_orig), z_orig, (x_mesh, y_mesh), method='linear')


sigma = [5, 5]
z_mesh = sp.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(z_mesh, sigma, mode='nearest')

# Create the contour
contourf = plt.contourf(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh, levels, alpha=0.9, colors=colors,
            linestyles='none', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

# Convert matplotlib contourf to geojson
geojson = geojsoncontour.contourf_to_geojson(
    contourf=contourf,
    min_angle_deg=3,
    ndigits=2,
    unit=unit,
    stroke_width=1,
    fill_opacity=0.3)
d = json.loads(geojson)
len_features=len(d['features'])
if not data:
    data.append(d)
else:
    for i in range(len(d['features'])):
      data[0]['features'].append(d['features'][i])

weather_json = json.loads(geojson)

###### Create the DataFrame #####

lats = [30,33,35,40]
lons = [-92,-94,-96,-100]
dat = [1000,2000,500,12500]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lats,lons,dat)), columns = ['lat', 'lon', 'data'])

##### Add the two on top of on another in a Dash Mapbox #####

# reading in the geospatial data for the state boundaries
states_json = json.loads(urlopen(r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkiefn1/SO_Json_Question/main/States_20m.geojson').read())

#creating outline of the US by joining state outlines into one multipolygon
usa = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(states_json['features'])
usa_poly = gpd.GeoSeries(unary_union(usa['geometry'])).iloc[0]

#geojson to geopandas
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(weather_json['features'])
#overlapping intersection of US poly with each contour
gdf['inter'] = gdf['geometry'].buffer(0).intersection(usa_poly)

#update weather_json
for n in range(len(gdf)):
    weather_json['features'][n]['geometry'] = mapping(gdf['inter'].iloc[n])


column = "data"

fig = px.density_mapbox(
df,
lat="lat",
lon="lon",
z=column,
hover_data={
    "lat": True,  # remove from hover data
    "lon": True,  # remove from hover data
    column: True,
},
center=dict(lat=38.5, lon=-96),
zoom=3,
radius=30,
opacity=0.4,
mapbox_style="carto-positron",
color_continuous_scale=['rgb(0,0,0)',
                         'rgb(19,48,239)',
                         'rgb(115,249,253)',
                         'rgb(114,245,77)',
                         'rgb(254,251,84)',
                         'rgb(235,70,38)'],
range_color = [0, 2000]
)

# Weather outlines
fig.update_layout(
mapbox={
    "layers": [
        {
            "source": f,
            "line": {"width":1},
            "type":"line",
            "type":"fill",
            "color": f["properties"]["fill"],
            "opacity": 1,
        }
        for f in weather_json["features"]
    ],
}
)

# States outlines
fig.update_layout(
mapbox={
    "layers": [
        {
            "source": g,
            "line": {"width":1},
            "type":"line",
            "color": 'black',
            "opacity": 0.5,
        }
        for g in states_json["features"]
    ],
}
)

fig.show()
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: When changing the loading of files from GitHub to locally on my machine, I get the following error code:

`TopologicalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e4ff6b512ee5> in <module>
--> 107 gdf['inter'] = gdf['geometry'].intersection(usa_poly)

....

TopologicalError: The operation 'GEOSIntersection_r' could not be performed. Likely cause is invalidity of the geometry <shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon object at 0x7fcf9a38f550>`

Comment: @Jkiefn1 That's weird, I've just run it again and it worked fine. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63955752/17142551 for a similar issue.

Comment: @Jkiefn1 out of curiosity, which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am attempting to run this code in a Jupyter Notebook. I get the error message even without changing anything from your original answer.

Comment: I've also tried this in the Python IDLE shell. Same error output.

Comment: @Jkiefn1 I've only ever tried it on IDLE, on two separate computers without issue. Is there any chance your libraries/packages are out of date?

Comment: After updating `geopandas`, `shapely`, and `geojson` this solution worked.

Comment: when simply changing `# col = 'Day_Temp'
# temp_levels = [-20,0,10,20,32]
# levels = temp_levels` to `col = 'Snow_in'
snow_levels = [0.1,0.5,1,3,5]
levels = snow_levels` the solution leaves behind remnants outside of the desired boundary.

Comment: @Jkiefn1 The answer was tailored specifically to the original problem. I've updated the code and it should now work for any situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the states_20m.geojson into a geodataframe. Then load the weather data into a geodataframe but set the parameter mask equal to the state geodataframe.

```
states=geopandas.read_file("states_20m.geojson")
weatherDF=pd.read_csv("date_data.csv")
weatherGeo=gpd.GeoDataFrame(weatherDF, geometry= gpd.points_from_xy(weatherDF['long'], weatherDF['lat'], crs="INSERT_CRS_HERE"))
weatherUS=weatherGeo.clip(states)
```

Hopefully this works!

Comment: This only removes the lat-longs from the data frame, but when creating the grid which the contour is then based off of using np.linspace, the un-wanted areas are still 'filled-in' in the contour.